# In line button with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Can anyone help to get this button vertically in-line (visually, not in a css sense) with the other input widgets?

```
require(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  verticalLayout(
    fluidRow(style = "background-color: orange;",
       column(3, actionButton('button', 'A button')),
       column(3, textInput('text', 'text', width = '100%')),
       column(3, selectizeInput('selectize1', 'letters', letters, multiple=TRUE)),
       column(3, selectizeInput('selectize2', 'LETTERS', LETTERS, multiple=TRUE))
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) { NULL }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Cheat by adding `tags$div(style = "height: 25px;")` above ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the div() function to edit html elements

```
require(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  verticalLayout(
    fluidRow(style = "background-color: orange;",
             column(3, div(align = "center",style="padding-top: 30px;width:100%", actionButton('button', 'A button'))),
             column(3, textInput('text', 'text', width = '100%')),
             column(3, selectizeInput('selectize1', 'letters', letters, multiple=TRUE)),
             column(3, selectizeInput('selectize2', 'LETTERS', LETTERS, multiple=TRUE))
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) { NULL }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

This did it:

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML("#button { margin-top: 25px; } ")))
```